# Computing correspondences between two images

Tags: image-processing

A classic problem in computer vision is computing correspondences between keypoints in two similar images, despite modest variations in size, lightness, orientation, etc., of the images, as illustrated [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/78554143388/).

Here are the two images I'd like to process (paintings by Jan van der Heyden):

[image: van der Heyden 1]
[image: van der Heyden 2]

Notice the differences in the cupolas (small towers), for example.

*Mathematica* implements this function by

```
ImageCorrespondingPoints[image1,image2]
```

but when I apply this function to these two paintings I get no more than five points total on each image.  (This is far too few for what I need to study, such as the larger deviation in correspondences for the cupola than for the buildings.)  I've adjusted `MaxFeatures` and other thresholds in `ImageCorrespondingPoints`, and even pre-processed each image (with contrast enhancement, etc.), tried different `Method`s such as "SURF" and "BRISK", but can never get more than about five such points.  This seems to be an (undocumented?) limitation of the function.

Traditional `ImageKeypoints` extracts enough points (after adjustment of `KeypointStrength`):

```
HighlightImage[image1, {AbsolutePointSize[8], Green, 
  ImageKeypoints[image1, KeypointStrength -> 0.002]}]
```

[image: image1 with many keypoints]

However, `ImageCorrespondingPoints` does not work on these highlighted images.

I've even tried `ImageDisplacements`, but without success.

I suppose I could get two lists of 2D locations of (many) keypoints for each image and write some RANSAC-like optimization, but I have a sense there is some easier way... some option or pre-processing I'm missing in this task.

---

Incidentally, my ultimate goal is to display these paintings side-by-side, with "good" correspondences linked by green lines, and "bad" correspondences (large deviation, as in the cupolas) in red lines.  This last step is not part of my question, as I'm confident I can write that code, once the core correspondence problem is solved.

Comment: Have you tried changing the key point identification method, or using a combination of methods? The default is “SURF”, but you could use a combination with `Method -> {“SURF”, “BRISK”, ...}` or whichever is most appropriate for your task.

Comment: Please report this behaviour to Wolfram.

Comment: @MarcoB:  Thanks for your suggestion, but `Method -> "SURF"`, etc., didn't help.

Comment: @AliHashmi It’s a bit rash to assume they don’t know about this. I’m sure  they could tune internal parameters and have it return a hundred correspondences, but the problem is that with an increasing number of correspondences you also get an increasing number of false correspondences. Indeed, my experience comparing Mathematica and OpenCV about two years ago was that with OpenCV I had more control, which meant I could tune it to find more correspondences, however it was hard to avoid spurious correspondences. Mathematica offers less control but the correspondences, as I recall, were very good.

Comment: C.E.:  Thanks.  I haven't tried *OpenCV* on these images, but expect it will perform better than *Mathematica*.  I'm trying to keep all the code for my current (big) project in *Mathematica*, but may have to resort to *OpenCV* at the end of the day.  It is true that *Mathematica* is quite good on "default" cases, but I would have thought that I'd be able to set some keypoint threshold or desired number of keypoints, but not so.  If anyone can kludge together some solution (perhaps by altering the underlying images), I'd be extremely grateful.  Regardless, I don't think it "rash" to alert WRI.

Comment: By "rash" I simply meant that I think it can be the kind of situation where at first it seems like it can be a problem, but upon experimenting more with it, one can see that it is probably intended. I've played around with this function quite a bit and it has worked for me. One big difference is that, as on the website you linked to, I used different photos of the same object. Two different painting of the same object is quite a big difference from photos of the same object, they are not expected to be exactly the same.

Comment: As a test, I generated keypoints using `ImageKeypoints` and got more than 300 for each image. I then, for each descriptor from image 1, I looked for the closest match among the descriptors of image 2. Then I did the reverse, i.e. for each descriptor in image 2 I looked at the closest descriptor among the descriptors for image 1. A common check to avoid spurious matches, which is an option in OpenCV, is to check that the best match is consistent. i.e. so matching points always find each other regardless how you do it. This was, unfortunately, not true for any of the more than 300 keypoints.

Comment: @C.E.:  Surely we both have seen correspondences computed for photographs that differ more severely than my two paintings, so the algorithms *should* work.  Your direct approach of finding the nearest correspondence is almost certainly far from optimal or correct.  After all, even a small rotation of one image will disrupt that algorithm.  This was the core computational problem solved by *RANSAC* and its descendants.  Regardless, I'm still at a loss on how to get the figure I need for my book using *Mathematica*.  WRI *should* produce hundreds of keypoints--otherwise the algorithm is useless.

Comment: Of course `ImageCorrespondingPoints` itself does nothing to infer 3D form, but is provides the *basis* for such subsequent processing.  (See the linked paper in my question.)  The fact that SURF etc. are rotationally invariant is irrelevant.  SURF finds corners of a building, windows, etc., which are then used for disparity-based calculation of depth.  (I and many others have done this.)  It is not the local rotation/transformation invariance of the features that is relevant, but instead the *global* rotation/transformation processing.  Look up "depth from disparity" and you'll see.

Comment: I simply misinterpreted your comment. I am familiar with the use cases for corresponding points. I hope you find a solution.